# why my custom object count is differ from system overview count?

Tags: apex, custom-object, customsetting

I am using below code to list all the custom object

```
Integer count = 0; 
for ( Schema.SObjectType o : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values() )
{
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objResult = o.getDescribe();
     if(objResult.isCustom())  
     {
         count++;
        //system.debug(objResult.getLabel());
    }
}
system.debug('Total custom object :'+ count);  

 // USER_DEBUG [11]|DEBUG|Total custom object :576
```

But when i see the system overview is different ? How to get this count match with system overview count. ?

SetUp -> System overview

[image] 
Custom object - 515

Custom setting -113

Finally got to know apex code gives all installed object which is not counted in UI data.

Comment: please use screen shot to explain what you mean by 'system overview'

Comment: There might be some deleted custom setting and object present in org. That are differing this count.

Comment: @cropredy Setup--> System overview  . This will give all custom object and custom settings count.

Comment: I am voting for closing this question, as you have asked new related one- [Why PersonAccount is showed in custom object in Tooling API query?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164140/why-personaccount-is-showed-in-custom-object-in-tooling-api-query). Please let us know otherwise.