# Why PersonAccount is showed in custom object in Tooling API query?

Tags: soql, tooling-api, person-accounts

I queried the below in the service console to get the custom object count. But I got one object difference. i.e "PersonAccount" .  When i check the ID its not displaying in the UI page.

> select id, DeveloperName, Description, ExternalName, ManageableState,
>   NamespacePrefix, SharingModel from CustomObject where ManageableState
>   != 'installed'

```
// Output
//Make sure you checked the tooling API checkbox when u run the query in console

//Count 514
```

> Setup-> System overview -> custom object count (513)

1 difference in object count.  Object name is  "PersonAccount"

Why is it showed here?

Comment: You have queried from Developer Console or Service Console?

Comment: PersonAccount is a standard object, maybe that is the cause.

Comment: @RahulSharma quried in  Developer Console

Comment: I am querying only custom objects . Then why i am seeing this in the result.

Comment: Check the API name of the object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an artifact from the special case that is [Person Accounts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=account_person_behavior.htm&language=nl&type=0) and how they appear as an optional addition to an org. Likely related to supporting Page Layouts, record types etc... for something that is otherwise covered by the existing Account and Contact records.

The Custom Object Overview from the System Overview will explicitly exclude it on the understanding that it is actually a native object.

Comment: +1 I got two object count different. One is person account. Another one i couldn't figure it out. I raised the support case. Lets see.

Answer (score 2):

We raised a support case to look what are the objects can be added in the system overview as custom object. Below are the initial response from salesforce support. I will share once i got final conclusion.

> Custom object count in system overview = ( Custom object + custom
>   settings ) locally created + unmanaged package objects + Nonsalesforce
>   Published managed Packaged Objects.  (Custom object from managed
>   package published by salesforce are not counted in system overview).
>
> NOTE: Soft deleted objects are not counted in System overview but
>   counted in tooling API, Hard deleted objects are not counted in both
>   System Overview & tooling API.
>
> If I enable knowledge user and enable knowledge settings a new
>   knowledge object is created in org which does not count in system
>   overview but counted in tooling API.
>
> Count in System Overview = 2 Count in Tooling API query = 3
>
> Tooling API’s SOQL capabilities for many metadata types allow you to
>   retrieve smaller pieces of metadata.
>
> I am still checking with my team for any more information.
>
> Thanks for your patience.